# "OR" construct in java recursion

Tags: java, recursion

Typically in a java program, if I have a construct like if (a || b), "b" is not evaluated if "a" turns out to be true. I am not able to understand how this would work in recursion.
Specifically, I looked at the solutions given in coding bat problem "splitarray"(given an array, find out if it can be separated into two groups so that their sums equal).

The solution code and the output (I put in the println to understand what is being called) is like this:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Main m=new Main();
        int[] x={1,4,3};
        m.splitArray(x);
    }

    public boolean splitArray(int[] nums) {
            return helper(0, nums, 0, 0,'M');
    }

    private boolean helper(int start, int[] nums, int sum1, int sum2,char ind) {
        System.out.println("calling Start="+start+" sum1="+sum1+" 
                           sum2="+sum2+" From="+ind);
        if (start >= nums.length) return sum1 == sum2;
        return helper(start + 1, nums, sum1 + nums[start], sum2,'L')
            || helper(start + 1, nums, sum1, sum2 + nums[start],'R');
    }
}
```

And the output:

```
calling Start=0 sum1=0 sum2=0 From=M
calling Start=1 sum1=1 sum2=0 From=L
calling Start=2 sum1=5 sum2=0 From=L
calling Start=3 sum1=8 sum2=0 From=L
calling Start=3 sum1=5 sum2=3 From=R
calling Start=2 sum1=1 sum2=4 From=R
calling Start=3 sum1=4 sum2=4 From=L
```

Can someone explain how this is progressing? Specifically I would like to know why the first call from "R" (second component of the OR ) does not start with sum1=8?

Thanks for your time

Comment: what is the contents of num[]? L helper call has sum1+nums[start] as sum1 and R has just sum[1]. I would assume num[3] is 3 so 5 + 3 is 8, and sum1 is just 5 so thats the difference

Comment: `a || b` works exactly the same with recursion as it normally works. The confusion from your side comes in from the values of the parameters being passed around, as Tyler pointed out.

Comment: When start is 3, it runs left side of your or check with sum1(5) + nums[start](must be 3 but you didn't provide the nums array to be certain) which produces the sum1 value 8 on output of line 4.  This ends up returning false, and so the right side of the check is run with just sum1(5) and so you get the results of line 5.

Comment: It may help you to visualize if you add another parameter (something like `level`) that you add one to on each call `helper(...., level + 1)`.  Then, in your println, add a tab character for each level at the beginning of each line.  This will visually give you a better idea on the recursion tree.

Comment: nums is {1,4,3} Added to the code fragment

Comment: If your question is "How does this work" I'm not sure stackoverflow is a good place to ask it. your goto tools "I don't get it" type of problems are the debugger and a whiteboard.